# superwebsocket on port 80

Tags: c#, iis, websocket, shared-hosting

I was playing with SuperWebSocket(http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com) and trying to make it work under shared hosting(i.e. port 80) as they don't allow other non standard ports. Is this possible to make it work on port 80? While I tried the server closes the connection. How to achieve that?

```
<socketServer>
        <servers>
            <server name="SuperWebSocket"
                    serviceName="SuperWebSocket"
                    ip="Any" port="80" mode="Async">
            </server>
            <server name="SecureSuperWebSocket"
                    serviceName="SuperWebSocket"
                    ip="Any" port="2012" mode="Sync" security="tls">
                <!--Please install the certificate to your trusted certificates store, the password is 'supersocket'-->
                <certificate filePath="localhost.pfx"
                             password="supersocket"
                             isEnabled="true"></certificate>
            </server>
        </servers>
        <services>
            <service name="SuperWebSocket"
                     type="SuperWebSocket.WebSocketServer, SuperWebSocket" />
        </services>
    </socketServer>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot bind a port which has been used.

Answer (score 0):

use wss://localhost:2012/ in your HTML file...it requires a secure connection